# Rails: prefixing the path of scoped routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using this code,

```
scope(:module => 'api', constraints: {subdomain: 'api'}, defaults: {format: 'json'}) do
  scope('1', module: 'v1') do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

the following routes are created:

```
posts     GET    /1/posts(.:format)          api/v1/posts#index {:format=>"json"}
          POST   /1/posts(.:format)          api/v1/posts#create {:format=>"json"}
new_post  GET    /1/posts/new(.:format)      api/v1/posts#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_post GET    /1/posts/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/posts#edit {:format=>"json"}
post      GET    /1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#show {:format=>"json"}
          PUT    /1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#update {:format=>"json"}
          DELETE /1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#destroy {:format=>"json"}
```

Scoping routes in an API namespace is useful, this way when the API change, there's not any collisions. Except for the path...

How can we prefix the path (with `v1` for instance), in order to have:

- v1_posts
- v1_new_post
- v1_edit_post
- v1_post

I tryied to add `:name_prefix => 'v1_'` like this:

```
scope('1', module: 'v1', name_prefix: 'v1_')
```

But this doesn't work.

Note: I'm working on Rails 3.2.2

Comment: Try https://github.com/intridea/grape

Comment: The build is currently broken, and for my needs this seems overkill. i would like to just do it with Rails itself.

Comment: you dont have to use master. Reinventing the wheel is always overkill. But I understand the feeling.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope module: 'admin', as: :v1 do
  resources :foobar
end
```

This gives paths like "v1_foobar_path"

Dunno if that's helpful.